# jQuery easytooltip IE6 & ID problems

Tags: jquery

I am trying to use multiple tooltips on the same page which works fine in FF, Chrome, IE8. IE6 & 7 however dont like the use of identical ID tags?

Im currently learning jQuery but not sure what I have to do to make both of these tooltips work, I've tried changing the IDs to classes etc to stop the clash but not getting anywhere.

Can anyone suggest how I can fix this problem?

Here is the page http://www.kylehouston.com/testing/easytooltip/hover-testing.html

Answer (score 4):

No browser likes duplicate IDs. IDs have to be **unique**! I wonder why it works at all...

I suggest you structure your elements like so (of course you should give them a more meaningful ID then just `linkX`):

```
<a id="link1" class="tooltip">...</a>
<a id="link2" class="tooltip">...</a>

<div id="link1-tooltip">...</div>
<div id="link2-tooltip">...</div>
```

And then loop over the links:

```
$('a.tooltip').each(function() {
    $(this).easyTooltip({
        useElement: this.id + "-tooltip"                   
    });
});
```